# UAC and Windows box selections in Windows

Tags: python, windows, com

So I'm using Python (though another language suggestion like C# or VB is fine too). I want to have a program launch an EXE file installer, and then tell that installer that it is alright to run the program using the UAC.

I would also like to be able to select buttons (click here to install!).

What library or language can do this? Where do I start? Would it deal with COM objects, or...?

Comment: In your context, it sounds as if the simplest solution would be to run your program as the special account named "Administrator".  By default, UAC is disabled when you are logged in with the Administrator account.

Comment: Alternatively, if your program knows the password for the admin account you are logged in with, you could use CreateProcessWithLogonW to launch the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you're using your powers for good, but the approach you suggest is essentially removing the safeguard that UAC was intended to provide for your users.  If they have configured UAC to run at a lower-than-maximum protection level, it might be possible to do what you want, but in general the UAC prompt is displayed in the secure desktop (that's why that background goes dark) and so no process of yours can automatically click its buttons.

Comment: That's more or less what I figured. I saw a solution on another question here that you could entirely disable UAC using registry hacks which, I suppose would be acceptable temporarily - this is a script that is only going to be run on new PCs and computers with newly loaded OSes. I was just hoping there was some way of showing I was a trusted application.